# Alternate solution to MediaStore DATE_TAKEN

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm using `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN` in my application. The date taken is accurate for existing images. However, for the newly added images, it would show up as `Jan 1, 1970`. What's even more bizarre is that the date would stay the same until I restart my phone, after which it will show up correctly.

**Note:** Same behavior on 2 devices, both running Android 10 (since `DATE_TAKEN` was added in `Q`) and from different manufacturers. A simple app restart doesn't work too.

**Edit**: I'm looking forward to an alternate solution to DATE_TAKEN. Below is the code that I'm currently using.

```
val projection = arrayOf(_ID, DISPLAY_NAME, DATE_TAKEN)
val sortOrder = "$DATE_TAKEN DESC"

app.contentResolver.query(
    EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    sortOrder
)?.use {

    val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_ID)
    val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DISPLAY_NAME)
    val dateColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DATE_TAKEN)
    while (it.moveToNext()) {
        val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
        val displayName = it.getString(nameColumn)
        val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
        val date = durationToDate(it.getLong(dateColumn))
        val img = Image(id, displayName, date, contentUri)
        result += img
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a bug report rather than a question

Comment: @Pawel What I'm looking forward to is an alternate solution to DATE_TAKEN. Let me edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: What i'm looking forward to is that you post the used code.

Comment: @blackapps Added the MediaStore code which I'm using :)

Comment: You should post the code with which you add images of course.

Comment: @blackapps I'm not adding images via my app, I just happen to download a few from Chrome when I noticed this weird behavior.

Comment: How would Chrome know when a picture was taken when it only downloads it?

Comment: `I'm using MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN in my application. ` If you start a post with such a sentence everybody here will suppose that your app saves to the mediastore and uses that column.